# WIFI not working or very slow, wired connection ok

Tags: wireless

I have found fixes for this problem using different hardware and find most solutions quite hard to follow, I am not very techy, please use small steps! Thanks.

Dell Inspiron 15R
20.04.3 LTS
ProtonVPN

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to give some information - what you’ve tried, what you think caused it … there’s just nothing to go on here.

Comment: Make model of a device doesn't mean that much; as products often change during production which is why companies like Dell use service tags allowing owners to find out what's actually inside their box. With GNU/Linux it's the chipset used that matters; you provided no details.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide maybe of help (esp. *Device Recognition and Operation* section which allows you to search online, or provide us with details needed to help you).

Comment: Being exact also helps, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? Desktop? which kernel tack did you opt to use (some ISOs give you a choice at install time, others are selected by the ISO you used to do your install; currently we don't even know if it's a Server or Desktop install you're asking about which influences the default...)

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, the only helpful information was from Alex Fullam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I went to `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`and found the following:

> [connection]
> wifi.powersave = 3

So I changed the `3` to `2`, rebooted, and the wifi connected faster.

The short answer to why this works is because you're essentially turning off wifi power management.

How to do it:

First, open a terminal window and type the following: `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`. You will have to enter your password since you are getting root permissions from `sudo`. Then, you can use your cursor keys to edit the file with `nano` and when you're done, do `ctrl`+`x` and then click `y` when it says "Save to modified buffer?" at the bottom. Then, reboot your system and you are good to go.

**Alternate Solution**

The first solution kind of stopped working for me, so I did this:
`sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf`. Then I replaced the line that started with `hosts:` with `hosts:          files dns`

**Essentially, you're fixing a bug in Avahi-daemon, which is a bug in Debian, but since Ubuntu is based off of Debian, it appears in Ubuntu as well.**

Then I rebooted.

Comment: Thanks for the information, can you please explain in baby steps how to get to the file, edit and save it?

Comment: @spider Ok! I'll edit my answer. :)

Comment: @spider I added the steps. Tell me if you need any more help!

Comment: Thanks very much, I followed the steps and it now works fine. Really pleased to be unplugged again!

Comment: OK so it's still not right, very slow just browsing, taking up to 20 seconds to load ebay homepage. I have tried with and without VPN, no change. I have checked the WIFI file and it is still set to 2, I have carried out a speedtest and get varying results from 20 to 60 mbps but still any web page takes ages. Any idea what I could check next?

Comment: @spider Uh oh! It didn't work? What DNS server are you using? I recommend Google's DNS server. Also, are you sure it's just not your internet?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for getting back, I have just booted the same machine on windows 10 and internet is fine- very fast. I am sorry but I am not sure what dns server I am using, it will be default as I have never tried to change it. I am averse to using google wherever possible. I have been using Ubuntu for years and re-installed it recently to try and fix this problem.

Comment: @spider Sorry for responding very very late, but does this help?
- edit /etc/nsswitch/conf
- Replace the line that starts with "hosts:" with "hosts:          files dns"
- Restart computer

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you very much for persisting with this, I tried it yesterday and it seemed to fix it straight away, still working today. I don't have a clue what it all means but I can confirm I have normal speed wifi and don't have to plug in any more. Thanks again.

Comment: @spider No problem! I'm so glad this helped.  If you're wondering what the solution did, you're essentially fixing a bug in Avahi-daemon.